# Can't pull image from private Azure Container Registry when using Az CLI to create a new Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I've created a service principal with push and pull access to/from my private Azure Container Registry. Pushing to ACR works perfectly fine with the following command:

```
az login --service-principal -u "someSpID" -p "someSpSecret"  --tenant "someTenantID"
az acr login --name "someRegistry"
docker push "someRegistry.azurecr.io/my-image:0.0.1"
```

And I am also able to pull the image directly with the following command:

```
docker pull "someRegistry.azurecr.io/my-image:0.0.1"
```

I want to deploy a container instance into a private subnet and I've configured the network security to allow access for my said subnet.

However, when I attempt to deploy a container instance with the following command into my private subnet, where I specified the same service principal which I had previously logged in with, I get an error response.

```
az container create \
  --name myContainerGroup \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --image "someRegistry.azurecr.io/my-image:0.0.1" \
  --os-type Linux \
  --protocol TCP \
  --registry-login-server someRegistry.azurecr.io \
  --registry-password someSpSecret \
  --registry-username someSpID \
  --vnet someVNET \
  --subnet someSubnet \
  --location someLocation \
  --ip-address Private
```

Error:

```
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): management.azure.com:443
urllib3.connectionpool : https://management.azure.com:443 "PUT /subscriptions/mySubscription/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/myContainerGroup?api-version=2018-10-01 HTTP/1.1" 400
msrest.http_logger : Response status: 400

The image 'someRegistry.azurecr.io/my-image:0.0.1' in container group 'myContainerGroup' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.
```

The same error ensues when I try and deploy the container instance through Azure Portal.

When I tried deploying a public image into the same subnet, it succeeds fine so it isn't a deployment permission issue, neither does it seem to be wrong service principal credentials as the `docker pull "someRegistry.azurecr.io/my-image:0.0.1"` works just fine. I can't quite wrap my head around this inconsistent behavior. Ideas anyone?

Comment: this looks fine, probably a typo with credential or wrong sp or you dont have access to pull

Comment: Do you check if the service principal has the right permission and the image tag i right?

Comment: @CharlesXu yes I have. The SP has the rights to pull/push and deploy. I tested this by manually logging into the docker registry and pull/push. So a new update is that when i changed `Allow access from` `Selected networks` to `All networks`, and added `az acr login --name "someRegistry" --username "someSpID" --password "someSpSecret` it works. However, we want to deploy this into a private VNET. Prior to this config change, the VNETs were already added in the selected network list. So I'm wondering whether this has to do with container instances network profiles

Comment: What about the image and tag? Are that all the same as you use?

Comment: Yes, image and tags are all the same.

Comment: Do you try to use the admin user?

Comment: Yes. Same error message ensues. `li.azure.cli.core.util : The image 'someRegistry.azurecr.io/my-image:0.0.1' in container group 'myContainerGroup' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.`

Comment: Do you create the container instance in the same subscription with the ACR?

Comment: Yup it's in the same subscription and resource group. On the subnet's end, we have temporarily disabled the NSG associate but the error still persists. Service endpoint has also been configured on the subnet's end

Comment: Then it's a strange thing. Do you check your local network? Maybe you can use another machine to try it.

Comment: Our local network is included in the list of IPs allowed in our firewall. And the error thrown back by the firewall would be a different error too. As for using a different machine, we've tried that too, as well as levering an actual deployment agent. I don't think its a problem with the internals of az CLI's `az container create` since creation through the portal throws the same error. From the likes of things, it seems that opening up the service endpoint for ACR on the subnet & our whitelisting of subnet on ACR's end is not sufficient

Comment: I am having the same issue, can use the registry from my own computer, but I can't run az container create, even tho credentials are specified in the az command and also in the YAML. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, here is a possible reason to explain the error you got. Let's look at the limitation describe [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-vnet#preview-limitations):

> Only an Azure Kubernetes Service cluster or Azure virtual machine can
>   be used as a host to access a container registry in a virtual network.
>   Other Azure services including Azure Container Instances aren't
>   currently supported.

This limitation shows the firewall of the Azure Container Registry does not support the Azure Container Instance currently. It only supports that pull/push the image in the Azure VM or AKS cluster.

So the solution for you is that change the rules to allow all network and then try again. Or use the AKS cluster, but it will also cost more.

Comment: Strangely enough, I actually got it working in a playground environment (with similar setup) hence I ignored that limitation specified in their docs. This issue only came about when I was trying to mimic the same setup in a new environment. Guess I'll get in touch with Microsoft to understand the nuances behind this disparity. Thanks though you were a great rubber ducky :) Will update once I get some news from Microsoft.

Comment: @theknees Well, I also want to know the difference. And if it's helpful you can accept it when you confirm.